# Write a function in R to extract the highest value of a variable in each data frame from a list of data frames

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, aggregate

I have a list of data frames:

```
df1 <- data.frame(day = c(1,2,3,4), price = c(100,120,90,22))
df2 <- data.frame(day = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), price = c(1,11,20,5,88,25,6))
my_list <- list(df1, df2)
```

I want to write a function which returns the max value of price and its corresponding day from both data frames.

Answer (score 3):

In base R, we can use `lapply` -

```
lapply(my_list, function(x) x[which.max(x$price), ])
```

Or using `dplyr` and `purrr` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

map(my_list, ~.x %>% slice(which.max(price)))

#[[1]]
#  day price
#1   2   120

#[[2]]
#  day price
#1   5    88
```

Comment: follow up question: can I use pipes as well? lets say I have repeating days (1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3) and I want to group by day and extract the max for each day.

Comment: You may add `group_by(day)` i.e `map(my_list, ~.x %>% group_by(day) %>% slice(which.max(price)))`